# NSMutableArray from filterUsingPredicate error

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nspredicate

I am trying to return a subset of my NSMutableArray (MessageArray) with the following code.  MessageArray contains an NSDictionary, one of the keys being FriendStatus.  I get a strange error which I know is a DUH syntax issue.  "error. void value not ignored as it ought to be".

```
-(NSMutableArray*)FriendMessageArray {  

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"FriendStatus == 1"];

NSMutableArray *filtered = [MessageArray filterUsingPredicate:predicate];
return filtered;
```

}

Comment: I understand now that filterUsingPredicate is a void that modifies the NSMutableArray.  It looks like I will have to make a copy of the NSMutableArray containing only the values I want unless there is a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*void value not ignored as it ought to be*" means that a method with a signature that starts with (void) is being used to assign a value or object to a variable. What's the signature for filterUsingPredicate? does it start with (void) ?

Comment: It does.  Now what?  I can't figure this out.

Comment: `-filterUsingPredicate:` modifies the original (mutable) array.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming "MessageArray" is an instance variable (never name instance variables this way; you should have a property called -messages and access it with self.messages). I'l further assume that it is an `NSMutableArray` or else you'd be getting warnings from the compiler.

`NSMutableArray -filterUsingPredicate:` modifies the array itself, returning void. The method you want is `-filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` which returns an array. The fact that the former is a verb and the latter is a noun indicates this fact even without reading the docs. Cocoa naming is extremely consistent, which is why I mention it in the first paragraph. Pay attention to the names and you will have far fewer bugs.

Comment: MessageArray is type NSMutableArray as I stated.  From my understanding, -filteredArrayUsingPredicate belongs to NSArray, and -filterUsingPredicate belongs to NSMutableArray.  Looks like I may be making a copy.

Comment: NSMutableArray is a subclass of NSArray. All NSArray methods are available for NSMutableArray.